# Counting number of medals in weekly tournaments

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I have a table holding weekly scores of players:

```
# select * from pref_money limit 5;
       id       | money |   yw
----------------+-------+---------
 OK32378280203  |   -27 | 2010-44
 OK274037315447 |   -56 | 2010-44
 OK19644992852  |     8 | 2010-44
 OK21807961329  |   114 | 2010-44
 FB1845091917   |   774 | 2010-44
(5 rows)
```

This SQL statement gets me the weekly winners and how many times each player has won:

```
# select x.id, count(x.id) from (
    select id,
           row_number() over(partition by yw order by money desc) as ranking
    from pref_money
) x
where x.ranking = 1 group by x.id;
           id           | count
------------------------+-------
 OK9521784953           |     1
 OK356310219480         |     1
 MR797911753357391363   |     1
 OK135366127143         |     1
 OK314685454941         |     1
 OK308121034308         |     1
 OK4087658302           |     5
 OK452217781481         |     6
....
```

I would like to save the latter number in the `medals` column of the players table:

```
# \d pref_users;
                   Table "public.pref_users"
   Column   |            Type             |     Modifiers
------------+-----------------------------+--------------------
 id         | character varying(32)       | not null
 first_name | character varying(64)       |
 last_name  | character varying(64)       |
 city       | character varying(64)       |
 medals     | integer                     | not null default 0
```

How to do this please? I can only think of using a temporary table, but there must be an easier way... Thank you

**UPDATE:**

The query suggested by Clodoaldo works, but now my cronjob occasionally fails with:

```
/* reset and then update medals count */
update pref_users set medals = 0;
psql:/home/afarber/bin/clean-database.sql:63: ERROR:  deadlock detected
DETAIL:  Process 31072 waits for ShareLock on transaction 124735679; blocked by process 30368.
Process 30368 waits for ShareLock on transaction 124735675; blocked by process 31072.
HINT:  See server log for query details.

update pref_users u
set medals = s.medals
from (
    select id, count(id) medals
    from (
        select id,
            row_number() over(partition by yw order by money desc) as ranking
        from pref_money where yw <> to_char(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'IYYY-IW')
    ) x
    where ranking = 1
    group by id
) s
where u.id = s.id;
```

Comment: What is the `medals`? Is it weekly wins count?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thanks to all for looking at my question

Comment: How frequently are you running that job? I suspect you are trying to update while the previous update is still running. How big are those tables? Not related but you should wrap those two updates in a transaction otherwise the zeroed medals will be momentarily visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update pref_users u
set medals = s.medals
from (
    select id, count(id) medals
    from (
        select id,
            row_number() over(partition by yw order by money desc) as ranking
        from pref_money
    ) x
    where ranking = 1
    group by id
) s
where u.id = s.id
```

Comment: Thank you! I merely had to add `update pref_users u set .... where u.id = s.id` because pgsql was complaining `column reference "id" is ambiguous`

Comment: @AlexanderFarber it is good practive not to use 'id' as column identifier but `pref_money_id` for the table `pref_money` by example. It makes easier to read queries and allow `NATURAL JOINS`.

Comment: @greg I would advise to use just `id`. About the `natural join` I think you got it backwards.

Comment: Do you maybe know why am I getting `ERROR:  deadlock detected`? Please see my updated question for details

Answer (score 1):

You could create a view which uses your "medal-select" and joins it with the actual data:

```
CREATE VIEW pref_money_medals AS
SELECT *
FROM pref_money
JOIN (SELECT count(x.id)
      FROM (SELECT id, row_number() 
            OVER(PARTITION BY yw ORDER BY money DESC) AS ranking
            FROM pref_money
            ) x
      WHERE x.ranking = 1 group by x.id) medals
ON pref_money.id = medals.id;
```